# jQuery ajax request results in a Not Found Error

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I' m new to MVC and was trying out some things but I can' t get this to work.

I have this script that should insert a partial view inside the page based on the dropdownlist selection.

```
$(function () {
    $('#ddTipologiaFattura').change(function () {
        var selectedID = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
           url: '/Admin/Fatturazione/GetPartial/' + selectedID,
           contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
           type: 'GET',
           dataType: 'html'
           })
           .success(function (result) {
               $('#partialPlaceHolder').html(result);
           })
           .error(function (xhr, status, error) {
               alert(status + '\n' + error)
           });
        });
   });
```

This is my controller **~/Areas/Admin/Controllers/FatturazioneController.cs**

```
    [RouteArea("Admin")]
    [Route("Fatturazione/{action}")]
    public class FatturazioneController : Controller
    {
        private MyEntity db = new MyEntity();

        public ActionResult GetPartial(int partialViewId)
        {
            if (partialViewId == 0)
            {
                var fatturaAziendaVM = new FatturaPerAziendaViewModel();
                ViewBag.Intestatario = new SelectList(db.Azienda, "AziendaNome", "AziendaNome");
                return PartialView("~/Areas/Admin/Views/Fatturazione/_ListaAziende.cshtml", fatturaAziendaVM);
            }
            var fatturaVM = new FatturaViewModel();
            return PartialView("~/Areas/Admin/Views/Fatturazione/_Intestatario.cshtml", fatturaVM);
        }
```

I keep getting a **Not Found** error by the script. 
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you access directly from your browser the URL you set for the AJAX request?

Comment: No, i can only access the other ActionResults from the controller that return a View and not a PartialView

Comment: I meant that you should try to make the request directly from your browser just to check if the URL is indeed accessible. This would be a first step in debugging your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your route only accounts for the action, not for the Id, which is why it's failing.  You should either update the route per action to account for the Id, or append the id as a query string parameter.

```
 $.ajax({
       url: '/Admin/Fatturazione/GetPartial?partialViewId=' + selectedID,
```